Multiple interfaces, with different configurations, on single NIC
I have a single network card and I want to attach two interfaces to it. One interface is DHCP and mtu: 1500. The other interface is a static IP and mtu: 9000.
How would I configure this via netplan or, if that's not possible, in systemd-networkd?

I ended up with this configuration. It seems to do what I need, giving me an interface with a static IP and mtu 9000 for the local network, and another interface through the same nic with a DHCP-assigned IP and mtu 1500 for internet traffic.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - veth0-peer
        - veth1-peer
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      mtu: 9000
  virtual-ethernets:
    veth0:
      peer: veth0-peer
      dhcp4: yes
      mtu: 1500
    veth0-peer: {}
    veth1:
      peer: veth1-peer
      dhcp4: no
      mtu: 9000
      addresses: [ 192.168.2.102/24 ]
    veth1-peer: {}

